# changing a process's parent

Tags: c, linux, process

Is it possible to change a process parent? 
ex: parent A has Child B can I make the parent of B is the Init process without killing A?

Comment: Is this homework / exam gotcha?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: while doing my homework this was a question come in my mind.I try to get rid of "Zombies" with various ways

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not from outside of process B.

From inside process B, you can call fork which makes a copy of your process, then let the original exit.  When that happens the new copy B2 will not be a child of A, its parent will be set to 1 (the init process).

Answer (score 17):

Calling `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, x, y)` where `pid` is the pid of B (in your example) and x and y don't matter (probably set them to NULL) will make the calling process the parent of B for many (but not all) purposes (with restrictions based on user ID of the processes, of course, to keep you from taking over someone else's processes unless you are root).

After calling `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,` the child will still get either its original parent or init's pid as its parent pid from `getppid()`, but the tracing process will be able to call `wait` and get `SIGCHLD` from process B.

There is a lot of stuff going on here, so you should read `man 2 ptrace` and make sure you understand the details pretty well.