# Handle end of execution

Tags: c, system, posix, fork

I'm making a little program using a lot of forks. The first parent have to wait for everychildren.
For only one child it's easy, there is the child-end signal (SIGCLHD). But what if my first child ends before the last child? My main program runs before the end of everychilds and I need the main program wait for children.

Each child ends with an execution of another program, that explain why I can't synchronize with something like semaphores.

```
// Working pretty good
execvp(
    c->command_name, /* program to execute */
    c->argv          /* argv of program to exécuter */
);
```

Here is my "fork-structure":

```
main
 |
 |------
 |     |
 |     |
 |     |------
 |     |     |
 |    EOE    |
 |           |
 |          EOE
 |
 |
EOE
```

*Legend:*

- *EOE means "End Of Execution*
- *The line top-bot is the timeline*
- *Each new step to the left is a new child.*
- *Each vertical bar represents the execution of a bar*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To find out which of the children process have terminated use `waitpid` in your SIGCHLD handler:

```
/* SIGCHLD handler. */
static void sigchld_hdl (int sig)
{
    pid_t child_pid;

    /* Wait for all dead processes.
     * We use a non-blocking call to be sure this signal handler will not
     * block if a child was cleaned up in another part of the program. */
    while ((child_pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
          // child_pid contains the terminated child process' pid
    }
}
```

For more details and a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) this snippet was based on, check out the [example's source](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/code-examples/SIGCHLD-handler).

EDIT:

So the question asks how to wait not only for the children, but for all descendants.

In pseudocode:

```
int alive_descendants = 0;

sigchld_handler() {
    decrement alive_descendants for each zombie;
}

int main() {
     setup-sigchld-handler;

     int fd[2];
     if (pipe(fd)) { error }

     to create a child:
         write a single byte to fd[1]
         fork off the child
         in the child process:
             close(fd[0]);
             to create child:
                  write a single byte to fd[1]
                  fork off the child
                  ...

     in the root process:
         close(fd[1]);
         for each byte read from fd[0], increment alive_descendants
         if alive_descendants == 0 and fd[0] is empty:
              ascertain that all descendants have terminated
              close(fd[0]);        
}
```

Comment: Which compiler allows you to declare a variable in the condition of a `while` loop?  The C standard does not allow that — though the C++ standard does allow it.

Comment: Hello, sorry. Maybe I poorly explained. I edited my post. (I tried your solution, the while end after the end of the first child)

Comment: @Nek `sigchld_hdl` does not necessarily run once processing all the children in one go, it may be called several times, each time processing only some of the children.

Comment: I tried your solution. Used a semaphore to stop the execution of the main process and the signal make the main process run again. The FIRST signal, I don't see how to dectect "how much" signals I will have...

Comment: @Nek Oh I see, you need to wait for grandchildren processes. How about creating a pipe, the write-end gets propagated to all descendent processes and the root process keeps the read-end?

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk Sometimes I need the pipe, sometimes not. I can't use this solution...

Comment: @Nek you can discard the pids you read from the pipe when you don't need to wait for processes.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk I don't understand... I cant use pipes since I used them for something else, isn't it ?

Comment: @Nek you can have as many pipes as you want (unless you hit MAX_OPEN_FILES): you don't have to `dup2` them to `stdout`.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk Can you show a little example in your answer ? I'm not sure to understand how I can do... Maybe a semaphore (for making the main process wait for pipes), a mmap (to store pipes) and ... A magical solution to check if descriptor is active of not ?

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk what do you mean by "zombie" in your sighandler ? By using the handler to decrement, aren't you suppose that the handler called for each child ? (because it's not, I just tested)

Comment: @Nek I assume you tested it with the code I linked to. If I amend it to increment a variable inside the while loop's body, I can see the variable incremented all the way up to 50, so, it works for me.

Comment: @Nek Oh, you're right! I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3842426/111160, maybe helpful.

Comment: @Nek or: instead of waiting for the descendants, just observe the process tree (make sure that when a parent terminates, his children are still visible in the process tree) and wait for when it contains only the root process.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
// for each child spawned:
children[i] = fork(); // children is an array of pid_t
if (children[i] == 0) {
    execvp(
        c->command_name, /* programme à exécuter */
        c->argv          /* argv du programme à exécuter */
    );

// parent process keeps doing its thing, and then
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHILDREN; i++) {
    waitpid(children[i], NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: This forces the parent to wait for each child to die in the sequence they're created.  It is often better to wait for 'any' child to die and then remove that from the list to be waited for.

Comment: I think the end-solution is more something like that. I should be able to share an array with all children which are going to add the new pid for each fork in the array. Something like mmap should work.