# Reattaching to processes in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I've following C program setup -> 1)- My parent process which forked one child process and then execl in that forked process to run another program. The forked program is in while(1) so it's always running. 2)- I've done waitpid in my parent process so that if child dies I shall know about it. 3)- Now what if parent itself dies? I still want to monitor that forked process. However, when my parent dies that forked process is owned by init. So init (process id =1) becomes the new parent of child process. But for some reasons i still want to reattach with my child process through some other program. Can I do it?

Comment: It's actually an orphan process in this case. But question remains the same. Can i again attach with that orphan process?

Comment: What happens if you again waitpid() in the new process? You have to save the child pid off to a file in the original parent process.

Comment: I had done the same. Stored the pid of that process and again waitpid on that. But unfortunately it doesn't work either, becaause waitpid can only be called for child processes by it's parent and in the case of orphan process init (pid =1) has become the parent so now waitpid throws an error saying- no child with this pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use`ptrace` with `PTRACE_ATTACH`, then you can do waitpid for that process. Please check `man ptrace` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842235/changing-a-processs-parent) for more information.

Below is from manpage of ptrace:

```
The ptrace() system call provides a means by which one process (the "tracer") may observe and control the execution of another process (the
       "tracee"), and examine and change the tracee's memory and registers.  It is primarily used to implement  breakpoint  debugging  and  system
       call tracing.
......
   PTRACE_ATTACH
          Attach to the process specified in pid, making it a tracee of the calling process.  The tracee is sent a SIGSTOP, but will not  nec‐
          essarily have stopped by the completion of this call; use waitpid(2) to wait for the tracee to stop.  See the "Attaching and detach‐
          ing" subsection for additional information.  (addr and data are ignored.)
```

Comment: sorry. Your answer doesn't help me. But rather it helped me know another aspect so I'll mark it as an answer.