# Create multiple child processes in UNIX

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fork

I want to write an UNIX program that creates `N` child processes, so that the first process creates one child process, then this child creates only one process that is its child, then the child of the child creates another child etc.
Here's my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int N=3;
    int i=0;

    printf("Creating %d children\n", N);
    printf("PARENT PROCESS\nMy pid is:%d \n",getpid() );
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        pid_t pid=fork();
        if(pid < 0)
        {
             perror("Fork error\n");
             return 1;  
        }
        else if (pid==0) /* child */
        {
            printf("CHILD My pid is:%d  my parent pid is %d\n",getpid(), getppid() );
        }
        else /* parrent */
        {
             exit(0);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I expect is in the form:

```
Creating 3 children
PARENT PROCESS
My pid is 1234
CHILD My pid is 4567 my parent pid is 1234
CHILD My pid is 3528 my parent pid is 4567
CHILD My pid is 5735 my parent pid is 3528
```

The output I get in the terminal is

```
Creating 3 children
PARENT PROCESS
My pid is:564
CHILD My pid is:5036  my parent pid is 564

User@User-PC ~
$ CHILD My pid is:4804  my parent pid is 1
CHILD My pid is:6412  my parent pid is 4804
```

The problem is that the program doesn't seem to terminate. I should use `Ctrl+C` to get out of the terminal, which is not normal. Can you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: You must have a `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’` when you compile. Try to add `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The children die when the parent dies. 
In your case the parent exits before all the children have been created.

Try waiting for the children before exiting:

```
    else /* parrent */
    {
        int returnStatus;    
        waitpid(pid, &returnStatus, 0);  // Parent process waits for child to terminate.
         exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions works fine and produces the desired output.
However, I do not understand why in my code the children die when the parrent died. As far as I know, it is possible for a children process to exist if his parent is dead.

Comment: Read these two: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158727/is-there-any-unix-variant-on-which-a-child-process-dies-with-its-parent    and  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94648/how-to-make-processes-not-die-after-its-parent-dies

Comment: Is it possible that the first process waits for the ending only of its son, but not of the other sub-sons?

Comment: Each process waits for it's child before exiting so the first parent will exit last.

Comment: OK,thank you, I got what you mean. But is it possible to write the program in a way so that the the very first process terminates first, the his child terminates second, the child of the child terminates third etc. How should I modify the code to make it work in this way?

Comment: There is another question on how to let a child survive its parent (be sure to read both answers, because they both provide valuble information):  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94648/how-to-make-processes-not-die-after-its-parent-dies

Just surviving your parent's death doesn't guarantee the order. Unfortunately,  `waitpid` only works for children, not for parents. A possible solution could involve `ptrace`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3842426/646887

Answer (score 0):

try to wait the process with wait(NULL);

```
pid_t child = fork();
if (child == -1)
{
  puts("error");
  exit(0);
}
else if (child == 0)
{
 // your action
}
else
{
 wait(&child);
 exit(0);
}
```

so your father will wait the child process to exit

Comment: I do not understand where is the difference between your proposition and the code of Klas. Klas uses waitpid(pid,&returnStatus,0) and thanks to this command the parant awaits its child to terminate.In my view, when you do wait(NULL) it has the same effect. Is it possible that the first process awaits the ending only of its child, but not of the other sub-sons?

Comment: It's just another option, i was too late,

Answer (score 0):

The proposed cure is correct, but the reason stated is wrong. Children *do not* die with the parent. The line

```
CHILD My pid is:4804  my parent pid is 1
```

clearly indicates that by the time child called `getppid()` its parent is already dead, and the child has been reparented to `init` (pid 1).

The real problem is that after the child prints its message, it continues to execute the loop, producing more children, making your program into a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Comment: Can you explain what to do so that the program creates exactly the specified number of children? Probably I should terminate the execution of each child by using exit(0). But when I put exit(0) in the child's code, the program creates only one process and not N.